# Add CASE into existing view

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-view

Is there any way to add CASE into existing MySQL VIEW? Or just only remove and create a new one with changes?

Comment: Try [ALTER VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-view.html)

Comment: `show create view` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-view.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ALTER VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-view.html). It will keep the existing permissions etc.

Comment: I read that ALTER VIEW syntax is the same as CREATE VIEW. Do I need to write full view logic, or just add new CASE?

Comment: You need to write the full definition of the view.